# How to use auth with CognitoUserSession and ApiClientFactory?

Tags: android, sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I'm trying to authenticate against an Amazon Cognito Api, however it's not working...

---

Creating a `CognitoUserPool` for registering and signing in works. But how to proceed form here on?

In `onSuccess(cognitoUserSession: CognitoUserSession)` gives me a session, from which I can get a `jwtToken` (`userSession.accessToken.jwtToken`).

How to use the session in combination with the ApiFactor?

```
val api: DevetrackcommercialplaygroundClient = ApiClientFactory()
            .apiKey(apiKey)
            .build(Client::class.java)

        val get= api.getFoo("id") // no auth; works
        val post = api.postBar("id", something) // has auth; doesn't work
```

Always gives me 401. Both, if I set `apiKey` to the api key and also if I set it to the `jwtToken`.

So how can I use `CognitoUserSession` and `ApiClientFactory` in conjunction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like *ApiGateway* is not really meant to be used with *user pools* as the whole requests would needs to be created manually without any help from the sdk - same goes for the response.
See https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/767

Maybe this will change at some point in the future:

> I agree with you that the Auth integration with API Gateway is not developer friendly and easy to use. We will take this feedback to the team to investigate on how to improve this integration. - *kvasukib*